# Which correlation test should I utilize to compare score data and total number of an event?

Tags: correlation

I have two fields in my dataset. The first field has records that return a final score (0-5) from the customer. The second field has records that show the total number of customer power outages.

I want to see if a correlation exists between these two. The values do not appear to be normal. Would I need to utilize Kendall's rank correlation tau?

Here is a snip of the dataset:

[image]

This is a scatter plot of the data:
[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you show us a scatter plot of the data?

Comment: @user2974951 added

Comment: The plot does not follow the description you mention in your text, one variable being from 0 to 5, are these the right variables? Anyway, one more request, can you add some jitter to the values and replace the old plot? Something like `plot(jitter(y)~jitter(x))`.

Comment: @user2974951 yes, sorry. I put together a quick example of what the data values look like. You are correct, the total_erts_given field is the total outages in the snippet and has values from 0 to 6 (0,1,2,...,6). The nps_numeric_final is the Survey Score field and really has values of 0 to 10 (0,1,2...,10). I have added jitter to the post.

Comment: The goal is also to do a breakpoint analysis between these two variables.